# The hupa itself, people holding or self standing, square or circle

Tags: minhag, marriage

I was told it is a segula to hold the 4 sticks of the hupa (square) so it seems it is preferred

But now I see a new (to me) minhag that they have fancy self standing ones, sometimes in the shape of a circle.

What is the history of these minhagim?

That is more preferable (square or circle and self standing or hand held) ? (All opinions)

(sources please)

Thank you

[image: photo of round chupa in Jerusalem]

Comment: Most, if not all, chupas I've been at were said standing